# How to avoid Deadlock when using singleton Http Client in Winforms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, deadlock

I have a legacy Windows Forms application that I am working on, I made some changes to the http client, I wanted to make it a singleton so that it could be reused throughout the application. It seems to be causing a deadlock.

I am going to paste all the code that I believe is involved below:

This is the calling code where the UI gets frozen, it never unfreezes.

```
private async void lbGroup_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int groupId = this.lbGroup.SelectedIndex + 1;
    await LoadStores(groupId);

    //The code below freezes the application
    this.lbStore.DataSource = _stores;
    
    this.txtSearch.Enabled = true;
    this.lbStore.Enabled = true;
}
```

This is the LoadStores Method where the httpClient is used:

```
private async Task LoadStores(int group)
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage res = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/GetStoresByGroup/" + group.ToString());
        res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var serializedStores = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _stores = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Store>>(serializedStores).Select(s => s.StoreName).ToList();
            res.Content.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogger.LogError("Installation", $"Error getting stores list: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

This is the Http Singleton Class:

```
public static class HttpClientSingleton
{
    private static readonly HttpClient _instance;

    static HttpClientSingleton()
    {
        _instance = new HttpClient();
        _instance.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.i-city.co.za/");
        _instance.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _instance.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public static HttpClient Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the form constructor where the HttpClient gets initiliazed:

```
public partial class frmInstallationHelper : Form
{
    private static string _configDir;
    private static string _localConfigDir;
    private static int _storeID;
    private static Activation _activation;
    private static HttpClient _httpClient = HttpClientSingleton.Instance;
    private static IEnumerable<string> _stores;
    private static IEnumerable<string> _franchisees;
    private int _smsCounter;
```

If I wrap the http request in a using statement inside of the LoadStores method, the app runs fine, but I don't want to dispose of the http Client as that defeats the purpose of making it a singleton.

**Update: Problem Found**

After following @MongZhu's lead I replicated the program and confirmed that none of the above code was actually causing the deadlock. It was caused by another method that was triggered by the lbStore list Box onSelectChange event displayd below:

```
private void lbStore_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string store = this.lbStore.GetItemText(this.lbStore.SelectedItem);
        LoadFranchisees(store).Wait();
        this.lbFranchisees.DataSource = _franchisees;
    }
```

The way I solved the problem was by changing it to look as follows:

```
private async void lbStore_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string store = this.lbStore.GetItemText(this.lbStore.SelectedItem);
         await LoadFranchisees(store);
         this.lbFranchisees.DataSource = _franchisees;
    }
```

I was busy changing all the .wait() methods to async / await, and I must have forgotten this one.

Comment: Should I just add a return; ?

Comment: @MongZhu async/await pattern does an implicit return of a task. returning a task is just wrong in this method or the return type has to be `Task<Task>`

Comment: are you using .NET 5 or Framework 4.8?

Comment: it's .net framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deadlock arises because you used `Wait` in a method which was triggered by an async opertaion. Unfortunately it was masked very good by the apparent hanging in the line of the initialization of the `DataSource`. But this initialization triggered the `SelectedIndexChanged` of the listbox which had the evil `Wait` call in it. Making this method async and await the result will evaporate the deadlock.

```
private async void lbStore_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string store = this.lbStore.GetItemText(this.lbStore.SelectedItem);
    _franchisees = await LoadFranchisees(store);
    this.lbFranchisees.DataSource = _franchisees;
}
```

I would suggest to return the `stores` directly from the method instead of using a class variable as transmitter. This way you would also avoid race conditions (to which methods that use class variables are very much prone) If you need it further you could store the returning value inside the `_stores` variable. But a loading method should rather return the results instead of secretely storing it somewhere hidden from the user of this method.

```
private async Task<List<Store>> LoadStores(int group)
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage res = await _httpClient.GetAsync("api/GetStoresByGroup/" + group.ToString()))
        res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var serializedStores = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            res.Content.Dispose();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Store>>(serializedStores).Select(s => s.StoreName).ToList();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogger.LogError("Installation", $"Error getting stores list: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

You can await the result in the event:

```
private async void lbGroup_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int groupId = this.lbGroup.SelectedIndex + 1;
    _stores = await LoadStores(groupId);
    this.lbStore.DataSource = _stores;
    
    this.txtSearch.Enabled = true;
    this.lbStore.Enabled = true;
}
```

The same logic applies to the `LoadFranchisees` method, refactor it so that it returns the data. This makes your code much more understandable. Don't hide information from the reader of a method. It could be you in 6 Month trying to figure out what da heck you did there.... Be nice to your future self at least ;)

Comment: The problem with that is that the _stores variable is being used again to further sort the data using some text.

Comment: I strongly advise against such an approach, especially in the context of async operations. Side effects a literally preprogramed if more than 1 task might operate on an object. " the _stores variable is being used again to further " where and how exactly? may be we can sort this also out.

Comment: There is a search box that is used to search the stores and display only the specified stores based on the input text. I am using a simple Linq Expression to search the existing _stores

Comment: I changed my code to return the stores from the method, it still results in the code freezing at the point where it tries to populate the lbStore.DataStore

Comment: @MervynLudick actually I cannot reproduce a deadlock from your posted example. I used your original code, but it never freezes. Something seems to be missing. I can get all the stores into the listbox

Comment: Did you also use a static http class? I am wondering if it's not something related to that, that is causing it, otherwise do you think I should upgrade to to a later version of .net framework?

Comment: @MervynLudick I copy pasted your original code, only had to write the `Store` class. But it is not freezing! neither in 4.6 nor in 4.8. That does not matter apparently

Comment: Did you put the methods inside of the Form class?

Comment: It seems to be a side effect of something else causing the deadlock, as I also replicated just that part of the app in a new application and it works just fine. I will try to look for the problem. Thank you for the help

Comment: @MervynLudick "Did you put the methods inside of the Form class?" Yes I did. For the eventhandler it is even necessary. When you find the difference please tell me, so we both can adjust our posts and bring this to conclusion :)

Comment: `private void lbStore_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.btNext.Enabled = true;
string store = this.lbStore.GetItemText(this.lbStore.SelectedItem);
LoadFranchisees(store).Wait();
this.lbFranchisees.DataSource = _franchisees;
this.lbFranchisees.Enabled = true;
}`

The listBox that was being populated had the above code on it's onChange method, this was causing the deadlock, I just changed the .wait to an await function. Not sure if I should just delete this question?

Comment: I actually thought about hat you might have also a `SelectedIndexChanged` event in the store listbox... Why delete? because it is so obvious that you had a `Wait` in there? Actually I would add this to your question. There will be people in future that will produce exactly the same situation. The deadlock is nicely hidden because the event is triggered when the datasource is initialized, thus making the appearance as if it would hang in the line that you identified, but in reality in deadlocks in the `Wait` line. But it is your decission.